# Configuring scheduler or timer service in Liberty

Tags: message-queue, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

We are migrating our code from WAS 8 to Liberty.In WAS 8 we have a configuration to place the updated policies to the Message Queue between 3 to 8 with 1 hour interval. We tried to imitate the same configuration in Liberty. Could anyone please help us on how to configure this

Answer (score 0):

EJB Persistent Timers are available in Liberty, Scheduler is not.

There are a lot of configuration options for EJB Persistent Timers, including whether you want Liberty to automatically create the tables that will be needed (this requires that the database user has authority to do so) or whether you want to do so manually, in which case Liberty can generate the DDL for you. You can find a lot of the advanced detail in this [knowledge center document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_config_ejbtimer_persistent.html).

However, the simplest solution accepting all of the defaults is to enable the ejbPersistentTimer feature and configure the DefaultDataSource, which will be automatically used by EJB Persistent Timers unless you configure otherwise.

Example server.xml snippet using Derby:

```
<server>
  <featureManager>
    <feature>ejbPersistentTimer-3.2</feature>
    ... your other features
  </featureManager>

  <dataSource id="DefaultDataSource">
    <containerAuthData user="user1" password="pwd1"/>
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DerbyLib"/>
    <properties.derby.embedded createDatabase="create" databaseName="timerdb"/>
  </dataSource>
  <library id="DerbyLib">
    <fileset dir="C:/Drivers/derby" includes="derby.jar"/>
  </library>
</server>
```